# Is possible play a video without canvas in the background on iOS/Android?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html

I knew in the iOS/Android are not allow play a video in the background, but today, I saw a website (at http://www.aolplatforms.com/onebyaol) it did this!
I feel incredible this page can play the html5 video streaming on iOS and Android. I have research it which is not using canvas to do this and which is using html5 video tag. I am very curious about why this page can do this?

.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I just went to this website, and then backgrounded safari on my iPhone, and the video paused when it went into the background?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can't play video in background without canvas. But fortunately you can use simply js plugin, for ex. https://github.com/tstabla/stVideo